Why do bacteria need the CRISPR system?
I'm learning about CRISPR at my college. I understand that when viral DNA is inserted into a bacterial cell, the Cas1-Cas2 proteins identify the PAM site in the viral DNA and then cut the protospacer from the viral DNA to make it a spacer in the CRISPR array for the adaptive immunity of the bacteria.
I'm confused about why a complex CRISPR system is necessary if the Cas1-Cas2 cuts the protospacer, and at that time only the viral DNA gets inactivated.

What do you mean by "a complex CRISPR system"? Every part of what you've noted makes sense to me except the question. Can you draw a picture of the system, point out what you understand, and what doesn't seem necessary? (Or more likely show some course materials)

My motive was to ask if the Cas1-Cas2 protein can cut the viral DNA by identifying the PAM site, and then the viral DNA gets inactivated. Then why do we need Cas9 then?

I'd suggest reading the Cas9 wikipedia page. If that doesn't make sense, you can come back and edit your question to indicate what you find confusing. (Ordinarily we ask posters to do some background research of this type as part of asking their question- see here about our homework policy and see here for a tour of the site to learn more.)
